# How to Access AsyncLocal

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

The classic .net [`CallContext`](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jeffreyr/logical-call-context-flowing-data-across-threads-appdomains-and-processes) was replaced with [`AsyncLocal`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html) in [.NET 4.6](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/07/20/announcing-net-framework-4-6/)...and is available in ASP.NET Core.  I notice that the latest version of [SimpleInjector is using it](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/aspnetintegration.html).

However, I am unable to use it in my `dnx451` ASP.NET Core project.

I can make the following two declarations:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
...
static ThreadLocal<string> foo = new ThreadLocal<string>();
static AsyncLocal<string> tenant = new AsyncLocal<string>();
```

The first one is fine, but the second one is not properly defined, as shown by this message:

```
AspAsyncLocal.DNX 4.5.1 - Not Available
AspAsyncLocal.DNX Core 5.0 - Available
```

What am I missing?  My project.json has the following dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
},

"frameworks": {
  "dnx451": {
    "dependencies": {
      "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
    }
  },
  "dnxcore50": { }
},
```

Comment: Have you tried using `dnx46` instead of `dnx451`?

Comment: `dnx46`? Since when was that an option?  The VS template defaults to `dnx451`, and the [list of available TFM's does not include `dnx46`](http://docs.nuget.org/create/targetframeworks).  Admittedly, I just now see the [.net platform standard mentions `dnx46`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md), but it says it is deprecated...and does not state what the replacement is.  Perhaps I need updated VS project templates?  Tools/extensions lists no updates.  Where do I get an up to date list of proper TFM's?

Comment: I think you could try `net46` - this area has seen a lot of churn after rc1. I expect there will be some documentation explaining this once this finally settles down.

Comment: Changing from `dnx451` to `dnx46` did indeed fix the problem.  Thank you!  Again, I didn't even know that `dnx46` was a legitimate, existing TFM.  I know there is a lot of churn, but I wish they would post a list... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `dnx46` instead of `dnx451`.